# VPS - MySQL and LAMP provided with hosting plans

Tags: vps

I wanted to buy a vps from a service provider but i have some concerns regarding the tools they install. I would like to build a java project and basically seems the linux based machines come by default with cPanel and LAMP stack. Therefore they say they offer MySQL by default for free with the hosting plan. But I am a concerned about using mysql in production. Is the MySQL from LAMP free? More hosting companies offer same setup. Can this mysql server they offer be used free in production? (to build a site that generates revenue) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I depends on you plan. But generally they are free, I mean comes as a bundle with the plan that you purchased.